# Load new Activity with animation when click on imageview without set enable in developer mode

Tags: android, android-animation

I want when click on ImageView activity loads with animation from right to left. It works fine if i set animation scale to 1x in developer mode but i want it without set animation in developer mode.

Animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXDelta="100%p"
android:toXDelta="0"
android:duration="500"/>
```

Animation2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXDelta="0"
android:toXDelta="-50%p"
android:duration="500"/>
```

And the imageview click code file is as follows:

```
imgswipeleft.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this) {
        public void onSwipeTop() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onSwipeRight() {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "RIGHT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EpubReaderActivity.class);
            Bundle bndlanimation = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.animation,R.anim.animation2).toBundle();
            startActivity(i,bndlanimation);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation,R.anim.animation2);

        }
        public void onSwipeBottom() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Can somebody please help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1x is a default animation scaling for Android devices. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @KonstantinKiriushyn But what if someone want to run the app who doesn't have enable developer mode. When i run apk after off developer mode it doesn't start activity with animation. Only animation work when i enable option. Which is not good...

Comment: Why is there no animation ? That makes no senses. The animation scale is set to 1 by default